# Index large DynamoDB table into Cloudsearch via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm currently facing an issue on CloudSearch when trying to index a large DynamoDB table via AWS Console:

```
Retrieving a subset of the table...
The request took too long to complete. Please try again or use the command line tools.
```

After looking throught the documentations[[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudsearch/index.html), [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudsearch/index.html), [3]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudsearchdomain/upload-documents.html), there are examples of uploading several file formats thought the CLI but no mention of uploading data from a DynamoDB table using the CLI.

How this could be done without having to download the entire database in a file and uploading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got in contact with AWS Support and there's not way of indexing DynamoDB data using the CLI.

The only available way is downloading the data and uploading though the CLI using a classical file format/structure(.csv, .json, .xml and .txt).

A shame, unfortunately.